# How to Get WebMethod's Return of String[][] in Android KSOAP2 Client

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services

I have a web method that returns a String[][] and I'm trying to parse the return in ksoap2 in android. I can't seem to understand how it is serialized, but all I'm trying to do is to get the return in a String[][] or ArrayList or Vector or any data structure. I'v tried them all and nothing seems to work. Here is my code.

```
    try 
    {     
        // connect to web service and call getUploadedMonthsYears web method
        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "getUploadedMonthsYears"); 
        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call("http://alfaisaliah.com/getUploadedMonthsYears", envelope);

        // create a serializable object that will hold the array of strings
        ks = (KvmSerializable)envelope.bodyIn;  
        monthsYears = new String[10][10];

        for(int i = 0; i < ks.getPropertyCount(); i++)
        {
            monthsYears[i][i] = ks.getProperty(i).toString();
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        return;
    }
```

the getUploadedMonthsYears() web method returns a String[][] as follows

month, year

```
1, 2011
2, 2011
3, 2011
1, 2012
```

and so on. thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar web service (Axis2) that returns a matrix of strings:

```
getCadenaResponse{return=anyType{array=hola; array=adios; }; return=anyType{array=hello; array=bye; }; return=anyType{array=bonjour; array=au revoir; }; }
```

It's an 3x2 matrix of strings. It's not a valid JSON response so I use some hack to split the response.

Try this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String NAMESPACE =  /* YOUR NAMESPACE */
private String METHOD_NAME = /* YOUR METHOD NAME */
private String URL = /* YOUR URL */
private TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =
        new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    try {
        transport.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME, envelope);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

        int cols = response.getPropertyCount();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            Object objectResponse = (Object) response.getProperty(i);
            String result = objectResponse.toString();
            String[] array = result.split(";");
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++) {
                String ss = array[j].substring(array[j].indexOf('='), array[j].length());
                list.add(ss);
                Log.v("TEST", ss);
            }
            matrix.add(list);
        }

        /* Here you have the matrix of strings in 'matrix' */

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This works for me, but I think that only works for primitive types included String.
Hope it helps.